# Insert custom PHP head above <html> in WP pages

Tags: php, headers, cookies, code, query-string

I've made a WordPress site. Before, I had a coded site in HTML. My new WordPress site is still in maintenance mode. But, I want to insert a PHP code above all the website content. This is my code:

```
<?php
//DETECT REFERRER
if(empty($_SESSION["referrer"]))
{
    $referrer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    if(empty($referrer))
        $referrer = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"].((!empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]))? '?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]:'');
    $_SESSION["referrer"] = $referrer;
}
//DETECT AFFILIATE ID 
if(empty($_SESSION["aid"])) 
{ 
    $aid = $_GET["aid"]; 
    if(empty($aid)) 
        $aid = $_COOKIE["aid"]; 
    if(empty($aid)) 
        $aid = 1; 
    setcookie("aid", $aid, strtotime("+10 years"), "/"); 
    $_SESSION["aid"] = $aid; 
} 
\?>
```

But I don't know how to insert it in avery page on my site. Is there any way to do this? If that's not possible, is there a different way to get a cookie when a query string is in the URL? Thanks in advance.

Regards, Luuk Faasse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WordPress theme should load `header.php` file for eacfront-endnd request, so the best place to add your custom code is in the `header.php` on the very top, before any HTML.

Comment: Thanks! But, now I have to insert a code that prints the value of the cookie. I have a code for that, but how to insert that into my page?

Comment: This hasn't really answered the question so shouldn't be marked as an answer...